# Add the recipient address to the application in ModernCV

Tags: moderncv

I am trying to add the recipient `\recipient{HR Departmnet}{Corporation\\123 Pleasant Lane\\12345 City, State}` to the application after the CV but I am getting nothing in the PDF file. How can I add the recipient to the application?

I just want to mention that all information in the CV is fake.

**Code**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[red]{casual} %[blue, green, orange, red, grey]{casual, classic}

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{4cm} %Laenge link
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\firstname{Alex}
\familyname{Baumann}
\title{Lebenslauf}
\address{Stek}
\mobile{0136/ 678 910 1112 }
\email{alex.baummann@gmail.com}
\photo[4cm]{fadisbild}
\begin{document}
\maketitle



\cvline{}{}{}
\cvline{}{}{}
\cvline{}{}{}
\cvline{}{}{}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% To remove the cover letter, comment out this entire block

\clearpage

\recipient{HR Departmnet}{Corporation\\123 Pleasant Lane\\12345 City, State}


\begin{justify}
Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,

\bigbreak

Ich bewerbe mich hiermit 

\cvline{}{}{}

Freundliche Grüße, \\
Alex Baumann

\end{justify}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to complete your letter as shown in the file `template.tex` of `moderncv`.

You missed the following lines:

```
\recipient{HR Department}{Corporation\\123 Pleasant Lane\\12345 City, State}
\date{January 01, 1984}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}% Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren
\closing{Yours faithfully,}% freundliche Grüße
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}          % use an optional argument to use a string other than "Enclosure", or redefine \enclname
\makelettertitle
```

and you should change your ending of the letter

```
Freundliche Grüße, \\
Alex Baumann
```

to:

```
\makeletterclosing
```

At last you do not need environment `justify`.

Please see the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[red]{casual} %[blue, green, orange, red, grey]{casual, classic}

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{4cm} %Laenge link
\setlength{\footskip}{42.5pt}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum} % blind text
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\firstname{Alex}
\familyname{Baumann}
\title{Lebenslauf}
\address{Stek}
\mobile{0136/ 678 910 1112}
\email{alex.baummann@gmail.com}
\photo[4cm]{example-image-A}%fadisbild


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\cvline{Test}{}{}
\cvline{}{}{}
\cvline{}{}{}
\cvline{}{}{}


\clearpage

\recipient{HR Department}{Corporation\\123 Pleasant Lane\\12345 City, State}
%\date{January 01, 1984} % english
\date{01.01.1984}        % german
\opening{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,} % Dear Sir or Madam,
\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen}% Yours faithfully,
%\enclosure[Anlagen]{curriculum vit\ae{}} 
\makelettertitle

\bigbreak

Ich bewerbe mich hiermit 

\lipsum[1]

\makeletterclosing % <==================================================

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: resulting page 2]

Comment: It seems more in line with [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) to use `\closing{Freundliche Grüße,}` and then `\makeletterclosing` since the user already specified `\firstname` and `\familyname`.

Comment: Is there any way to generate the German date version in the application without adding it explicitly `\date{January 01, 1984}`?

Comment: @TheBook Sorry, did not noticed you wrote an comment. The date `01.01.1984` Is a german variant for for `1. Jan. 1984` oder `1. Januar 1984`. With package `datetime2` you can change the date to be printed in all three variants ...